# Parse.User not returning a value on iOS for AngularJS + Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, parse-platform

I am developing an app using [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com) which is built using Cordova and AngularJS.

I have been using Parse.com for the backend of the app. The app has been functioning fine on the emulator and on Android.

However after loading the app on an iPhone (tried it on a 4S, 5, 5S and 6), the User Query returns an empty array.

Here is the code:

```
var userquery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userquery.startsWith("username", $scope.search.queryvalue);
userquery.notEqualTo("username", $rootScope.sessionUser.get("username"));
userquery.limit(20);
userquery.find({
  success: function(result) {
    $scope.people = result;
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

As mentioned before, this code returns the right result when using the iOS Emulator and when testing the app on an Android Device. However on an iPhone is does not work.

Anyone faced such an issue?

**UPDATE:**

After doing some more testing with some console logs I found another error. The problem is that the variable that is taken in through an input text box adds some strange REGEX parameters.

`console.log(userquery);`

This is what the output looks like

```
{"where":{"username":{"$regex":"^\\QTanuj\\E","$ne":"test"},"id":{"$ne":"46JOEKKKF1"}},"limit":20}
```

Again, this is only happening on an iPhone. Anyone know why `{"$regex":"^\\Q` and `\\E"` is being added around the search query value `Tanuj`?

Could this be an AngularJS issue? Is there a way to force AngularJS to not put the variable through regex?

**Further UPDATE:**

Here are the console logs from the emulator:

```
{"where":{"username":{"$regex":"^\\Qtanuj\\E","$ne":"test"},"id":{"$ne":"46JOEKKKF1"}},"limit":20}
```

This is boggling my mind. The values work even with the $regex bit while on the emulator. But as soon as it goes on the phone, the result is blank.

This is the console logs of the result on the iPhone: `result: []`

But on the emulator, it returns the expected values.

What could the problem be?

Comment: When you say "returns an empty array", is it actually returning, if you add code to the result, does it get called?  iOS is very cache heavy, it often will not make the call at all, to save battery life and network calls for the users.  You might want to check that it is actually making the call.  I see what you are showing as console logs, but I do not see them in the code.